# Memory leak when using MNP package in R

Tags: r, memory, package, limit

I have a question concerning memory use in R when using the MNP package. My goal is to estimate a multinomial probit model and then using the model to predict choices on a large set of data. I have split the predictor data in a list of pieces.

The problem is that when I loop over the list to predict, the memory used by R grows constantly and uses swap space after reaching the maximum memory of my computer. The allocated memory is not released even when hitting those boundaries. This happens even though I do not create any additional objects and so I don't understand what is going on.

Below I pasted an example code that suffers from the described problem. When running the example, the memory grows constantly and remains used even after removing all variables and calling `gc()`.

The real data I have is much larger than what is generated in the example, so I need to find a workaround.

My questions are:

**Why does this script use so much memory?**

**How can force R to release the allocated memory after each step?**

```
library(MNP)

nr <- 10000
draws <- 500
pieces <- 100

# Create artificial training data
trainingData <- data.frame(y = sample(c(1,2,3), nr, rep = T), x1 = sample(1:nr), x2 = sample(1:nr), x3 = sample(1:nr))

# Create artificial predictor data
predictorData <- list()
for(i in 1:pieces){
    predictorData[[i]] <- data.frame(y = NA, x1 = sample(1:nr), x2 = sample(1:nr), x3 = sample(1:nr))
}

# Estimate multinomial probit
mnp.out <- mnp(y ~ x1 + x2, trainingData, n.draws = draws)

# Predict using predictor data
predicted <- list()
for(i in 1:length(predictorData)){
    cat('|')
    mnp.pred <- predict(mnp.out, predictorData[[i]], type = 'prob')$p
    mnp.pred <- colnames(mnp.pred)[apply(mnp.pred, 1, which.max)]
    predicted[[i]] <- mnp.pred
    rm(mnp.pred)
    gc()
}

# Unite output into one string
predicted <- factor(unlist(predicted))
```

Here are the output statistics after running the script:

```
> rm(list = ls())
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 158950  8.5     407500  21.8   407500  21.8
Vcells 142001  1.1   33026373 252.0 61418067 468.6
```

Here are my specifications of R:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MNP_2.6-2   MASS_7.3-14
```

Comment: After running the above script (including rm() and gc()) the memory use on my computer is the following: `RSIZE 5661M, VPRVT 6108M, VSIZE 9500M`

Comment: This is peculiar.  What was the virtual memory usage before running this?  As for the resident memory, this can be bogus - sometimes these are buffers that can be reclaimed by the OS.  If OSX has `free`, try it and report that info.  Also, what happens if you use the most recent version of R?  I see that there's no more recent version of MNP.

Answer (score 1):

The results don't seem anomalous, as in I don't think this evidences a memory leak.  I suspect that you're misreading the data from `gc()`: the right hand column is the maximum memory used during the tracking of memory by R.  If you use `gc(reset = TRUE)`, then the maximum shown will be the memory used in the LHS, i.e. the 8.5MB and 1.1MB listed under "used".

I suspect that MNP just consumes a lot of memory during the prediction phase, so there's not much that can be done, other than to break up the prediction data into even smaller chunks, with fewer rows.

If you have multiple cores, you might consider using the `foreach` package, along with `doSMP` or `doMC`, as this will give you the speedup of independent calculations and the benefit of clearing the RAM allocated after each iteration of the loop is complete (as it involves a fork of R that uses a separate memory space, I believe).

Comment: Using the `foreach` package could solve part of the problem, its a good idea. The problem in the predictor loop remains though. At least on my computer the memory used by R in this script grows steadily and is only released upon quitting R. I edited the script and increased the nr of pieces to 100. If I run the edited script on my computer, the predictor loop makes the memory use grow and the memory is not released even when it reaches the maximum ram (it just starts using swap space).

Comment: If `foreach` doesn't work out, I guess it's best to contact the maintainer.  You might also try the Unix utility `valgrind` to see if there are any memory leaks that show up.  I assume this also works on OS X.